# Trying to create a Keycloak user with spring rest client

Tags: java, spring, rest

Here's the error message:

400 Bad Request: [Unrecognized field "rep" (class org.keycloak.representations.idm.UserRepresentation), not marked as ignorable]

Here's some code:

```
public String createUser2() throws UnsupportedEncodingException, JSONException {

    String adminToken = getAccessToken();
    
    System.out.println("token: " + adminToken);

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.set("Content-Type", "application/json");
    headers.set("Authorization", "Bearer " + adminToken);
    
    UserRepresentation userRepresentation = new UserRepresentation();
    userRepresentation.setFirstName("some");
    userRepresentation.setLastName("user");
    userRepresentation.setUsername("Some.User@somewhere.com");
    userRepresentation.setEmail("Some.User@somewhere.com");
```

//      Gson gson = new Gson();
//      String jsonString = gson.toJson(userRepresentation);

```
    MultiValueMap<String, UserRepresentation> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, UserRepresentation>();
    map.add("rep", userRepresentation);
    
    HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, UserRepresentation>> request = new HttpEntity<>(map, headers);
    
    String uri = "http://10.127.2.46:31680/auth/admin/realms/12xDemo/users";
    System.out.println("URI: " + uri);
    
    UserRepresentation response = (new RestTemplate()).postForObject(uri, request, UserRepresentation.class);
    //JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);

    return (new Gson()).toJson(response);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you should send `HttpEntity<UserRepresentation>`as a request. Cause your server code waits for this type and receives "rep": "UserRepresentation", tries to map it on actual UserRepresentation.class